# Read tabulated numeric data in C++ with the minimum number of code lines

Tags: c++, io

Getting used to the simplicity of the input/output operations in scripting languages like Python, R or Matlab, I find that simple operations like reading tabulated numeric data in C++ are unnecessarily complicated.

So, I am wondering what is the shortest code snippet (not necessarily with the STD library, other libraries are admitted) in C++ that may read an arbitrary large numerical, tab separated, table of data (floats) in a format suitable for later mathematical manipulations (statistics and so on)?

Comment: `std::vector<float> data; float num; while(std::cin >> num) data.push_back(num);`

Comment: I guess your answer is certainly right. The only con is that I loose the table structure (accessing columns/rows), which is a pity for the statistics, but technically I guess you answered the  question as I have expressed it. One can always slice the vector afterwards...

Answer (score 1):

If you want your data in a large 2D matrix that you can access using row and column indexes, I prefer the stringstream and istream_iterator approach.

```
vector<vector<double>> data;

ifstream is("path\to\your\file.txt");

for (string row; getline(is, row); ) {
    stringstream ss(row);
    data.push_back(vector<double>(istream_iterator<double>(ss), istream_iterator<double>()));
}
```

Comment: I have actually had a look at [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net). The minimal code seems very short in this case...
`arma::mat A ;A.load("data.dat")` But this is not STD

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Record {
    int f1;
    float f2;
    char f3[20];
};

std::vector<Record> recs;
for (string line; getline(cin, line); ) {
    Record rec;
    if (3 == sscanf(line.c_str(), "%d,%f,%20s", &rec.f1, &rec.f2, &rec.f3)) {
        recs.push_back(rec);
    }
}
```

If you want a totally generic vector-of-strings, you can look at Boost for its string algorithm split() and pass in your delimiter.  I prefer the structured approach when possible.

Another way is to actually let Python do the work: you can embed a Python interpreter in your C++ program and use something like `numpy.loadtxt()` to load the data into a NumPy array, then access it from C++.  I do rather the converse operation here: https://github.com/jzwinck/pccl/blob/master/NumPyArray.hpp